# Python error when trying to save a new file: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, error-handling, xlwt

I am getting the above error when trying to create a new workbook with the following commands:

```
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
workbook.save(‘my_file.xls’)
```

I am new to Python and following a guide but I can’t find what this error means

Comment: can you able to add your error's stack trace by editing your question, so that it will be helpful for other newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. I think your workbook needs to be setup with a sheet to be valid.

```
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
workbook.add_sheet("Sheet")
workbook.save("myfile.xlsm")
```